# Solving the SPOJ Problems

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying out to solve this problem,

with this reference cpp codes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
long double integral(long double h,long double w,long double f,long double x)
{
 return -(w-2*x)*sqrt((w*w*w*w+16*h*h*(w-2*x)*(w-2*x))/(w*w*w*w))/4
  -(w*w*asinh(4*h*(w-2*x)/(w*w)))/(16*h);
}
long double objective(long double h,long double w,long double f,long double d)
{
 return 2*(f*d+integral(h,w,f,w/2)-integral(h,w,f,d));
}
int main()
{
 for (;;)
 {
  long double h,w,f;
  scanf("%Lf %Lf %Lf",&h,&w,&f);
  if (h==0) return 0;
  long double a=64*(h*h);
  long double b=-64*(h*h)*w;
  long double c=16*(h*h)*(w*w)+(w*w*w*w)-(f*f)*(w*w*w*w);
//  printf("a=%Lf b=%Lf c=%Lf\n",a,b,c);
  long double disc=b*b-4*a*c;
  long double x1,x2;
  if (disc<0) x1=x2=-1;
  if (disc>=0)
  {
   x1=(-b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
   x2=(-b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
  }
//  printf("x1=%Lf x2=%Lf\n",x1,x2);
  pair<long double,long double> res;
  res.first=1e200;
  res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,0),0.0L));
  res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,w/2),w/2));
  if (x1>=0&&x1<=w/2)
   res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,x1),x1));
  if (x2>=0&&x2<=w/2)
   res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,x2),x2));
//  printf("%.3Lf\n",res.second);
  printf("%.3Lf\n",4*h/(w*w)*(res.second-w/2)*(res.second-w/2)+1e-15);
 }
}
```

actually i want to convert it to C language programming, but i was confusing when i reach the

```
pair<<long double,long double> res;
```

and continue untill last line of this code.
Some referecne told me that in C programming that i should use a struct so i build it, then the codes be like here :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <math.h>

typedef struct
{
    long double first;
    long double second;
}pair; res;

long double integral(long double h, long double w, long double f, long double x)
{
    return -(w-2*x)*sqrt((w*w*w*w+16*h*h*(w-2*x)*(w-2*x))/(w*w*w*w))/4
  -(w*w*asinh(4*h*(w-2*x)/(w*w)))/(16*h);
}

long double objective(long double h,long double w,long double f,long double d)
{
 return 2*(f*d+integral(h,w,f,w/2)-integral(h,w,f,d));
}

int main()
{
    for(;;)
    {
        long double h,w,f;
        scanf("%Lf %Lf %Lf", &h, &w, &f);
        if (h==0) return 0;
        long double a=64*(h*h);
        long double b=-64*(h*h)*w;
        long double c=16*(h*h)*(w*w)+(w*w*w*w)-(f*f)*(w*w*w*w);
        long double disc=b*b-4*a*c;
        long double x1,x2;
        if (disc<0) x1=x2=-1;
        if (disc>=0)
        {
            x1=(-b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
            x2=(-b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
        }
        printf("x1=%Lf x2=%Lf\n",x1,x2);

        res.first=1e200;
        res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,0),0.0L));
        res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,w/2),w/2));
        if (x1>=0&&x1<=w/2)
        res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,x1),x1));
        if (x2>=0&&x2<=w/2)
        res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,x2),x2));
        //  printf("%.3Lf\n",res.second);
        printf("%.3Lf\n",4*h/(w*w)*(res.second-w/2)*(res.second-w/2)+1e-15);


   }
}
```

The question is how can i convert the codes in this section

```
        res.first=1e200;
        res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,0),0.0L));
        res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,w/2),w/2));
        if (x1>=0&&x1<=w/2)
        res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,x1),x1));
        if (x2>=0&&x2<=w/2)
        res=min(res,make_pair(objective(h,w,f,x2),x2));
        //  printf("%.3Lf\n",res.second);
        printf("%.3Lf\n",4*h/(w*w)*(res.second-w/2)*(res.second-w/2)+1e-15);
```

into the C language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A C++ *pair* is basically a struct of two elements in C.

You replace

```
pair<<long double,long double> res;
```

with (note that your code has a `; res;` that has to be fixed)

```
typedef struct {
    long double first;
    long double second;
} pair;
pair res;  // <====
```

For convenience you could add (in C, a function can return a struct)

```
pair make_pair(long double a, long double b) {
   pair p;
   p.first = a;
   p.second = b;
   return p;
}
```

And the C++ *pair* `<` does `return lhs.first<rhs.first || (!(rhs.first<lhs.first) && lhs.second<rhs.second)`, thus we write the C functions

```
pair min(pair a, pair b) {
   return a.first<b.first || (!(b.first<a.first) && a.second<b.second) ? a:b;
}
```

Then you don't have to change the rest of the code, since the C++ standard methods have been "polyfilled" into C functions.

Always compile with all the Warnings ON (in gcc: the `-Wall` option).

Comment: I just need to combine your nice answer and explanation and i got the point that in C we need to add manually the pair just not like the C++ one, which is have a pair function. Thank you,